# print the value of the current language from the database in laravel

Tags: laravel, localization

I have simple question but i don't know how to do that ,

I need to print something like that in laravel

```
{!!mb_strimwidth($allProduct->content_."trans('language.lang')", 0, 75, "...")!!}
```

which I want to make `trans('language.lang')` get me **( en or ar )** for example , so it will get me the value of the current language and print it like that

```
{!!mb_strimwidth($allProduct->content_en", 0, 75, "...")!!}
{!!mb_strimwidth($allProduct->content_ar", 0, 75, "...")!!}
```

How can i do that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a property by string with curly brackets (`{}`).

Like so:

```
{!! mb_strimwidth($allProduct->{'content_' . trans('language.lang')}, 0, 75, "...") !!}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to make that with this line : 
{{$lastProduct->'title_'.trans('pagination.slaglan')}}

Comment: exactly the same, but replace the string `content_` and the value of the `trans` function.

Comment: It giving me that error :
syntax error, unexpected ''title_'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: when i type this : 
{{$lastProduct->{'title_'.trans('pagination.slaglan')}}}
it give me this error : 
syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: It's working by using this line : 
{{($lastProduct->{'title_'.trans('pagination.slaglan')})}}<